# Unable to create description in descriptionForLayoutAttribute_layoutItem_coefficient. Something is nil iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I am getting this strange error mentioned above if i choose deployment target below iOS 8 and even my app crashes on iphone with iOS version below iOS 8.0 .I think it has to do something with auto layout but i am not getting any errors or warnings for my constraints.

I am using Xcode 6.

So can anybody guide me how can i get rid of this problem.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer to a similar question may helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26045383/415219

The gist seems to be that versions of iOS prior to iOS 8.0 do not like the "Constrain to Margins" option when pinning constraints.

Comment: I've already solved it with the help of same link you suggested ,but thanks for reply.