# Auto-layout giving 8 spacing for top bottom and leading

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I am new to auto-layout in IB and am having some issues. I am creating a new TableViewCell using a .xib file.  I have a cell with the height of 130 and width of 320. I have another plain uiview within the cell and that has a width of 120 with the top,bottom, and leading spacing set to 0. I want the edge to align to the super view, it only works if i set the spacings to -8... Does anyone know what I can be doing wrong and why there is automatically 8 spacing added for me?

Here is a screenshot.[image: Magic 8 spacing for top/bottom/leading added...]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6 Check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you targeting iOS8 then the new introduces [layout margins](http://carpeaqua.com/2014/07/24/auto-layout-in-ios-8-layout-margins/) can lead to this observation.

Edit: From the linked post here is how to change the layout margins:

```
myView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, but why not tell OP how to change them?