# What does "Constrain to margins" mean in Interface Builder in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: swift, interface-builder, autolayout, xcode6, margins

I understand the purpose of "Spacing to the nearest neighbor" (in Xcode 6, more especially in Interface Builder) but **what is the point of "Constrain to margins"?**

**Is there a link between "Spacing to the nearest neighbor" an edge of a particular control button, and the fact of at the same time checking the checkbox named "Constrain to margins"?**

**What is the role of this feature in Autolayout?**

Please find a screenshot with the checkbox and the label that I am talking about surrounded in red below:

[image: Constrain to margins screenshot]

([Screenshot above in bigger format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SVBL.png))

Thank you in advance for your answers to my three questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is "Constrain to margin" in Storyboard in Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6)

Comment: I have checked the link of the post but the best explanation is: "in iOS 8 you now have the option to define your constrains relative to a predefined margin to the superview's bounds, instead of the superview's bounds themselves.". Sorry but it is not clear and does not mean anything for me, that is why I ask to clarify this obscure answer and explanation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

iOS8 introduces a new property of the UIView: `layoutMargins`. Shortly: these 4 values (a `UIEdgeInsets`) represent the margins of the view: its subviews can now be positioned relative to these margins, or the old way relative to the sides.
I wrote an [article about this in my blog](http://coding.tabasoft.it/ios/ios8-layout-margins/) with more details, let me know if it is clear and if you have additional doubts.

Comment: Thank you very much dude, I will study the article on your blog and will let you know.

Comment: My god am i glad i found this. The -16 pixel stuff was driving me crazy as things were not working on iPhone 6 plus. Removing the relative to margin on the constraints fixed it, thank you!