# Putting a UIViewController in a XIB makes constraints disagree with frame

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, xib

Immediate children of the UIViewController's `view` outlet have a weird 16pt horizontal padding in constraint space but not frame space.

1. Add a UIViewController to a XIB file in Xcode 6
2. Add a subview to the UIViewController's `view`
3. Stretch the subview so that its leading and trailing edges touch the superview
4. Click on the pinning constraints button
5. Observe that IB wants to add -16pt distances from the subview to its superview

Where is this discrepancy coming from?  How can I get my subview to stay constrained to the superview's edges?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pin constraints popover, uncheck "Constrain to margins".

There is some more discussion of this feature here: [What is "Constrain to margin" in Storyboard in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6)