# Why does not the webview fit all the view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, constraints

I have a simple webview in a viewcontroller and I want it to cover all the viewcontroller

**So I've added 4 constraints:**

[image]

**But this is the result:**
[image]

As you see the webview is not covering all the space: on the left and on the right there is empty space... how can I fix this?

Comment: You have 'constrain to margins' checked in the constraints dialog. Try unchecking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deselected the `constrains to margin` button under spacing to nearest neighbor.

Here is some explain about `constrains to margin` [What is "Constrain to margin" in Storyboard in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6)

"Basically if the layout margins are 8,8,8,8 (the default), a constraint with 0 leading space to container margin will have an x position of 8. Note that this is only available on iOS8 or later."