# What is the difference between Top and TopMargin in NSLayoutAttribute?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

I am trying to create a constraint via code:

```
constraintImageCharacterTop = NSLayoutConstraint (item: image,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: viewTop)
    self.view.addConstraint(constraintImageCharacterTop)
```

However, I am not sure which is the right `NSLayoutAttribute` for this constraint. `image` should have a top space to the main Superview `self.view`.

This is how I think it works, but I am not sure if I am correct:

[image: Imgur]

Should I use `NSLayoutAttribute.Top` or `NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin` for image A?

Comment: see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That question explains things a little bit but does not answer my question.

Comment: I usually don't use constraint to margin, it is a personal preference, either to constraint to the edge of the view or to constrain to its margin (8px).
Let's say your Image A has a top of 8px, you could create a top constraint with a constant of 8, or a top margin constraint with a constant of 0, you will get the same result.

Comment: Thank you! So are you saying that creating a top margin constraint of 0px is equal to create a top constraint of 8 px?

Comment: Yes, as long as the margins remain 8px

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: Thank you, don't hesitate to hit me up if you need more help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually don't use constraint to margin, it is a personal preference, either to constraint to the edge of the view or to constrain to its margin (8px). Let's say your Image A has a top of 8px, you could create a top constraint with a constant of 8, or a top margin constraint with a constant of 0, you will get the same result.