# Difference between NSLayoutAttribute "Top" and "TopMarigin"

Tags: ios, autolayout

Can any one please explain the difference between `NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin` and `NSLayoutAttributeTop`, I googled it but didn't find any clear solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSLayoutAttributeTop aligns to the top of the container. NSLayoutTopMargin aligns to the top margin of the container, which is 8 points below the top of the container by default on iOS8.

See this answer for a great description of margins: [What is "Constrain to margin" in Storyboard in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6)