# Why the leading space is -20 when adding a constrain on super view

Tags: ios, constraints

I added a subView inside a super view. They have same x-location. Then I added a leading constrain between these two but the constrain value is -20. I faced this issue many times. I don't know why they seems aligned together but the constrain is -20 different.

Comment: Check the comments here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875187/why-do-i-have-to-set-trailing-space-to-16-in-interface-builder-to-get-full-scre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margins are different for each device size.

The right way to set the space between the boundaries and your view to 0 is to uncheck the `constrain to margins` checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because the default constraints are relative to margin. If you don't want the -20, uncheck the "constraint to margins."