# View with constraints changes when run on simulator

Tags: ios, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UISegmentedControl`, in a static `UITableViewCell`. I'm added `constraints` on all 4 sides. I want the `segmentedControl` to have squared corners. I set it up in the storyboard to look like that, and it looks fine. But when I run it on the simulator, you can see the rounded edges. (I don't get any warnings.)

**Storyboard:** (This is how it should look)
[image]

**Constraints:**

[image]

**Simulator:**

[image]

Comment: What happens when run on a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is because of view's margins. Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692783/1310204) for a good explanation of what margins are, and how to deal with them.