# AutoLayout constraints to UITableViewCell contentView not respected

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I'm trying to create dynamically resizing table view cells. I accomplished the resizing by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights), which is very detailed and helpful.

However, the maximum width for the label is not being calculated correctly in`heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

My cell currently only has one label in its`contentView`, with constraints set to pin all the label edges to the`contentView` edges. Here's what I have in IB
[image]

The cell size is being calculated with an offscreen cell in`heightForRowAtIndexPath` using

```
CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
```

During this process, it seems like it's honoring the constraints, and the `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property is being set to 320, but when the label actually gets rendered, there is still padding.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The paddings is layout margins. You have to be beware of `Constrain to margins` option.

`Constrain to margins` is Enabled:
[image]

`Constrain to margins` is Disabled:
[image]

**How to disable it?**

1. You can double-click the one of constrains and unchecking the `Relative to margin` option:

[image]
[image]

2. Unchecking the `Constrain to margins` while creating the constraints of the label:

[image]

Related link:
[What is "Constrain to margin" in Storyboard in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6#28692783)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been searching for this for hours