# iOS: why margins are always -20?

Tags: ios, alignment, viewcontroller, margin

This is something that always happens, but I never understood.

Why in Interface Builder, if you leading-align a view with the view controller, the margin shows up as -20, instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a negative number, it means the contraint you set has the "relative to margin" option checked.

I found the solution here:

[What is "Constrain to margin" in Storyboard in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6)