# Canvas Boundaries Don't Match 4s Phone or Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, canvas

When I constrain a view to the left or right edge of the screen (Landscape) and compile for the iPhone 4 (my only development device) the content appears off the edge of the screen on both the device and the simulator. But the phone and simulator are off by different amounts.  On the phone I have to inset the view by 12 points and in the simulator it is 4 points.  The bottom edge seems to match the canvas.  All edges match on the iPhone 5s simulator and an iPad simulation (didn't try them all).

My questions are:

1. What is going on? Is this Normal? Is it just the iPhone 4?
2. Should I not try to go to the edge of the screen? Do I need to inset all of my content by a certain amount? How much?

   I can't test on every device so I need to know that my layout will work based on the design on the storyboard and the simulator.

XCODE 7.2.1

Deployment Target: 7.0

Edit: The view I was placing had "Constrain to Margins" checked.  This is not compatible with IOS 7.  Unchecking this seems to have solved the problem in the simulator.  I will have to wait until I get back to my test station to see if the device works properly.

Edit 2:  Unchecking "Constrain to Margins" did indeed fix the problem on the iPhone 4 device.  The iPhone 4 cannot be upgraded past iOS 7.x so I guess I have to find the money to buy some newer development devices:(

Comment: Are you adding constraints with or without margins?

Comment: I am ignorant enough that I am not sure.  However, in the "pin tool" the for the view I am placing: "constrain to margins" is checked.  For the superview it is NOT checked.

Comment: Thats what I meant "constrain to margin". On iOS 8 and above If you add a constraint with 0 space with margin checked it will have 8 space. That doesn't effect iOS7 devices.

Comment: If you want you can check more detailed explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6