# UIView origin is not equal to zero

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

I setup a view controller scene with interface builder. I add a view to my controller and add a custom class (CustomView) to it.

[image]

The view controller code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myCustomView: CustomView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print(myCustomView.frame.origin)
    }

}
```

**The question**

Why the origin of `myCustomView` is equal to (-4.0, 64.0) and not (0, 64) ?

Comment: try to pinned edges without constraints to margin and than check

Comment: Which values you set in contrains?

Comment: @James my constrains are on the right of my screen shot

Comment: @EICaptain Yes that works ! I disabled constraints to margin and now I have the origin I expected ! Thanks

Comment: @EICaptain Yes of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add the constraints,your constraints to margin remains unchecked. Because of `constraints to margin` it gives you a frame that starts with (-4.0,64.0) like that...

Try to pinned all your edges without constraints to margin that will solve your problem ..

For more guide about constraints to margin, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6)