# text in label bleeding off screen iOS Swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, uilabel, constraints, uitableview

I'm added in two labels into a table cell, the top one being left justified and the bottom being right justified, however the text isn't displaying properly.

I added the proper constraints for the tableview in storyboard but that hasn't resolved the issue.  Here is the code i used to set up the labels and the resulting screenshot, I'm only using the borders for debugging purposes

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


    var label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height/3))
    var label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,cell.bounds.height/3, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height/3 * 2))



    label1.textAlignment = .Left
    label1.text = "AAAA"
    label1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    label1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0


    label2.textAlignment = .Right
    label2.text = "BBBB"
    label2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    label2.layer.borderWidth = 1.0


    cell.addSubview(label1)
    cell.addSubview(label2)
```

[image]

**edit:** adding in new picture to show constraints

[image]

Comment: please post your constraints

Comment: adding new picture to post @EICaptain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `constraints to margin` when pinned all you edges ..

For more guide about constraints to margin, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6)

Comment: perfect! thank you! the text is starting right at the edge - do you happen to have a quick tip as to how to add some padding?

Comment: and if possible add label in cell and add constraints .. this is just a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any constraints on the `cell` itself. I'd recommend that you subclass `UITableViewCell`, add the two labels to the custom cell, set up constrains, and then modify those labels in `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Then you'll keep constraints as set up in storyboard.

As it currently exists, you are creating new `labels` each time a cell is loaded, so you would have to create constrains programmatically as well, which is not ideal.

Comment: i was hoping to avoid this step, it looks like the answer above is working

Comment: It will make your code cleaner and more efficient, but glad it's working.