# UITableView is 8 points wider than UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I'm adding a `UITableView` to my `UIViewController` using Interface Builder. Setting up leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to my superview margins somehow makes the tableView 8 points wider than my viewController.

Here's the view hierarchy:

[image]

The constraints:

[image]

ViewController view during runtime using Xcode visual debugger:

[image]

TableView during runtime using Xcode visual debugger:

[image]

the 8 points seems suspicious and I picture it has something to do with margins, though I'm not able to figure it out.

**Why is the tableView wider than my viewController?**

Comment: is it affecting your app performance or UI at all?

Comment: @user3353890 yes, because I'm using a UIPageViewController and it slides over the other VCs

Comment: don't give constraints to margins. uncheck this option when you are giving the constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Uncheck it before u give constraint

Comment: Why does it constrain to margins by default?

Comment: @Erik to understand that check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 0):

remove old constraints . Click on add new . Uncheck Constrain to margin as shown below[image]

Actually by Default story board adds this (Don't know why , any one else can comment about that).