# Layout relative to margin warning XCode 6 but with no constraints

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, constraints, xcode6

I have the dreaded warning `Attribute Unavailable: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width is not available on iOS versions prior to 8.0`, but in my case, `Margin` does not appear in the storyboard, and the label in question (the one that is highlighted when I click on the warning) has no constraints. In fact, the entire view has no constraints.

I have seen other posts, eg. [Attribute Unavailable warning on iOS versions prior to 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275901/attribute-unavailable-warning-on-ios-versions-prior-to-8-0), but as I said no `Margin` to find, and no constraint to edit.

I will add constraints and hope it goes away, but it looks like another bug...

Answer (score 19):

I think I've seen the same things for UILabels in Interface Builder. For me, the warning goes away by checking this box.

[image: Preferred width]

Comment: I've done the same and the warning goes away. But what semantic does it involves?