# Xcode 6 - Issue with 4inch screen and iOS 7

Tags: xcode, ios7, uiview, ios8, xcode6

I have developed a new app from scratch using Xcode 6.
I have built the app in the "Base" and I set the constraints for all iphones and works perfect.
When I run the app on iPhone 5 or iPhone 5S for iOS 7 I have a black space from the top of the screen but the app is fine for theses devices on iOS8. (I added all the launchimages for all iOS(7+8) and for all sizes.
This is a screenshot with the issue:

[image]

Comment: Give us some more information on the constraints, especially the view that is problematic.

Comment: all the views are problematics. If there was a problem with constraints it should be with the image view on the background which I set to stretch up,down,right left of each view. I tried to place some other "views" on the "black space" but nothing happened. its like a dead spot.

Comment: also have in mind that there is a navigation bar which is transparent

Comment: Can you check out top layout guide and margins on iOS8? You might have margins on there, disable all constraints to margins and relative to margins option as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261326/layout-attributes-relative-to-the-layout-margin-on-ios-versions-prior-to-8-0/25420909#25420909

Comment: Thanks for your time Legoless. I found the solution and I am posting it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the constraints of the ImageView. I remove them all and then I set the UIImageView to have equal width and height with the parent UIView. Then I set constraints to keep the UIImageView on the center - both vertically and horizontally.