# UIView layoutMargins in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

There is a new property of `UIView`: `layoutMargin` in iOS8.

In order to set the margins of a view programmatically:

```
self.view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
```

Is it possible to set margins in Interface Builder?

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25261327/1728118

Z.

Comment: I can't find a way either.  :(

Comment: Why do not use IBInspectable properties? Add for fields (Top, Left, Bottom, Right coz Insets aren't supported yet) to new extension for UIViewController and the values in IB

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by setting a `User Defined Runtime Attribute` in the `Identity Inspector`:

[image: screenshot 1]

Although Xcode does have a margins setting, as of `7.3 (7D175)`, it still doesn't have any effect, so you have to use the user defined attribute:

[image: screenshot 2]