# Storyboard warning : First baseline layout attribute before iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, storyboard, warnings, xcode-storyboard

I can't figure out how to get rid of this warning, I'm using a storyboard with many viewControllers (with labels, textfields and a lot of constraints ) all of them have been created almost the same way.

[image]

When I click on the warning it highlights a UILabel inside a scrollView :

[image]

This scrollView has many UILabels with constraints, I tried everything I could find on so including : [Attribute Unavailable: First baseline layout attribute on iOS versions prior to 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557692/attribute-unavailable-first-baseline-layout-attribute-on-ios-versions-prior-to)

This Warning doesn't cause my app to crash,I've tried on the simulator and an iPhone 4 (ios 7.1.2). But I'm worried about the AppStore approval.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue is you have many constraints that are using `NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline` and when you click on the warning Xcode is pointing to wrong constraint.

To identify the constraints search in Xcode with "firstBaseline". Change all constraints that are using `NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline`.

[image]

Note: You may need to adjust your views. In my case `NSLayoutAttributeBaseline` worked well.

> NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline
>   The object’s baseline. For objects with more than one line of text, this is the baseline for the topmost line of text.
>   The object’s baseline. For objects with more than one line of text, this is the baseline for the topmost line of text.
>   Available in iOS 8.0 and later.
>
> NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
>   The object’s baseline.
>   The object’s baseline.
>   Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot, (I have  to wait another 8h to give you the bounty award)

Comment: Thanks. Actually waiting is good. It means more people will see this question and more chance of getting an up-vote ;)

Comment: Brilliant answer. But just want to add that where to search is "Document outline" not the xcode itself.