# What is auto layout Baseline?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

When i use Auto Layout i typically attach objects to bottom, instead of baseline. But what is - baseline? I could not find good answer from apple docs, either on SO.

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html) i only figured out that baseline is just a horizontal line, that is upper from bottom, but lower the centered Y line.

Can someone provide explanation what is it and why should anyone use it? For me it is much more easier to just attach view to bottom.

Comment: The baseline is the line on which the text "sits": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188488/understanding-firstbaseline-vs-baseline-autolayout-constraint

Comment: @MartinR ok, that is not referred to ios i guess, thanks)

Comment: @JoGoFo This is a different question.  This is the diff between `baseline` and `bottom`.  Your question is diff between `baseline` and `firstBaseline`.

Answer (score 4):

According to Apple docs, the baseline of a `UILabel` or other UI element with text is the "vertical alignment of the text within the label".  In the docs for `UIView` it states:

> When you make a constraint to a view’s baseline attribute, Auto Layout
>   uses the baseline of the view returned by this method. If that view
>   does not have a baseline, Auto Layout uses the view’s bottom edge

Comment: when you define a term X, please don't put X itself in it's own definition